# How to not to turn array into hash in lua (prevent array become hash )?

Tags: arrays, hash, lua, lua-table

If i write in Lua

```
local var = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Variable *var* is array.

If i want to keep it as array (not hash), i must use table.insert, table.remove etc.

This code will turn it into hash:

```
var["key"] = 4
```

QUESTION: 
Does this code turn array variable into hash?

```
local var = {1,2,3,4,5}
var[4] = "string"
var[6] = "string"
var[1] = "string"
```

Comment: You are not forced to use table.insert etc,.

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed, Lua only has tables. Internally, the values you put in the table, may be stored in its array or hash part, but it's an implementation detail that users don't need to worry about.

In your particular case, the keys will be stored in the array part only (even after assignment), as you are not creating any new keys. According to a detailed description in  [Lua Performance Tips](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf) ("About tables" section), the initial assignment will allocate 6 slots in the array part and then you just re-assign those. If you add `var[7] = "string"`, then this value goes into the hash part and this will trigger a re-hash as the hash part has size 0 at this point. Lua will calculate how many slots are needed to accommodate all values in the array part (7 now) and "chooses as the size of the array part the largest power of 2 such that more than half the elements of the array part are filled".The array part will now have 8 slots and the hash part will still have size 0 as there are no elements to go there.

> QUESTION: Does this code turn array variable into hash?

So the answer to this question is "no" (if by "turn into hash" you mean that the table gets a non-zero hash part). If you do `var[8] = "string"` (without assigning `var[7]`), the hash part will get non-zero size, but if you later do `var[7] = "string"`, this will trigger another re-hash as this element won't fit in the hash part and all these elements will be assigned to the array part again.

Lua is trying hard to keep the most appropriate structure for the elements you have in the table, but the changes to the structure itself are only done during re-hashing.

Comment: Thanks! @paul-kulchenko The best answer! Still have one question.... If i write:  `local var = {}; for i = 1, 10000, 1 do table.insert ( var, i ) end; var[5] = { some = false, another = 2 }; var[888] = @userdata; var[10000] = {}; var[1] = 1 `  Will this make from var hash or it will still be array-like table? ( ";" sign is for separate ) ( I think the answer is "no", becouse as you wrote it will not touch th structure of table... is this right? )

Comment: That's correct; you are only changing the values of various elements in the array part, without changing the structure of the table. You can store values of various types (everything that Lua support as a type) in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to draw a distinction between "arrays" and "hashes" which does not exist in Lua. They're all tables. Some of them just have keys which aren't all positive integers.